# Getting cpu usage realtime

Tags: command-line, top

When I execute following command to get cpu usage , I get nice + user cpu usage.

```
top -b -n1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | awk '{print $2 + $4}'
```

Output:

```
14.5
```

Here I am getting problem is that the output depends on top command thus it doesn't change instantly as top command. So I am not getting correct cpu instantly. It gives same output and not changing.

I want to get real-time cpu usage in output. Please help me to improve my command.

Comment: real time monitoring http://askubuntu.com/questions/293426/system-monitoring-tools-for-ubuntu/293447#293447

Comment: This simple bash script does just that: http://askubuntu.com/a/450136/243213

Answer (score 25):

If you can afford a delay of one second, this will print CPU usage as a simple percentage:

```
echo $[100-$(vmstat 1 2|tail -1|awk '{print $15}')]
```

(Without the one-second delay, [`vmstat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/yakkety/man8/vmstat.8.html) can only print average values since boot.)

Comment: Doesn't give me an accurate % (comparing with htop)

Comment: You need to use `vmstat 1 2` like this:  `echo $[100-$(vmstat 1 2|tail -1|awk '{print $15}')]`  Otherwise your `vmstat` is going to give values _since boot_ which is likely not what you're after.

Comment: joe thank you it works. please Paul, edit the answer so that everyone can see the correct command line

Comment: Thanks for catching that, Joe and Pavlos! I didn't notice that part of the man page.

Answer (score 12):

This is a known issue with `top`.  As explained [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=174619), the 1st iteration of `top -b` returns the percentages since boot, we therefore need at least two iterations (`-n 2`) to get the current percentage. To speed things up, you can set the `d`elay between iterations to `0.01`. `top` splits CPU usage between user, system processes and `nice` processes, we want the sum of the three. Finally, you `grep` the line containing the CPU percentages and then use `gawk` to sum user, system and nice processes:

```
    top -bn 2 -d 0.01 | grep '^%Cpu' | tail -n 1 | gawk '{print $2+$4+$6}'
        -----  ------   -----------    ---------   ----------------------
          |      |           |             |             |------> add the values
          |      |           |             |--> keep only the 2nd iteration
          |      |           |----------------> keep only the CPU use lines
          |      |----------------------------> set the delay between runs
          |-----------------------------------> run twice in batch mode
```

Comment: Every other method including sar, mpstat... etc shows a 2/3% whereas this command always shows 50%.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai the numbers should change (I just checked it) are you sure you copy/pasted it correctly? Also, note that on systems with multiple CPUs, `top` will report the % usage as a percentage of a _single_ CPU. This means you will often get much higher percentages. See point 9 [here](http://superuser.com/a/575330/151431).

Comment: I think this command might not be compatible with my system. But it's apparent that all the other methods I tried gets me a percentage of 1/2/3% which is what I see if I run htop, whereas this command gives me an anomaly.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai that's because of the multiple CPUs. You can either get the number returned by this and divide by the number of cores or you can use `top` in interactive mode (just run `top`) and, once there, hit `I` (shift + i) to see a breakdown by cores.

Comment: I have only 1 CPU.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai yes, but it probably has multiple cores. What does  `grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo` return? If that's `1` you have a buggy `top` but that's very unlikely.

Comment: No I mean this is inside VirtualBox, I've assigned only 1 vCPU, so there's only 1 processor 1 core.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai I just tested on a VM with a single CPU and it works as expected. It does often show high usage but that's because the usage was actually high in that specific millisecond. Remember that `top` itself can actually cause a spike in CPU usage.

Comment: Do we need `gawk` for that?

Answer (score 8):

I have tried several ways, but this seems to me the most accurate:

```
cat <(grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat) <(sleep 1 && grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat) | awk -v RS="" '{print ($13-$2+$15-$4)*100/($13-$2+$15-$4+$16-$5)}'
```

Got it from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69185/getting-cpu-usage-same-every-time/69194#69194)

Comment: my linux (Linux machine_name 4.4.0-127-generic #153-Ubuntu SMP Sat May 19 10:58:46 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux) does not have column $15 (cpu line of the /proc/stat file): cpu  17411187 27478 594887 646652526 585551 0 31838 0 0 0

Comment: Best answer! Thanks! My variation: 
cat <(grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat) <(sleep 0.1 && grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat) | awk -v RS="" '{printf "%.1f", ($13-$2+$15-$4)*100/($13-$2+$15-$4+$16-$5)}'

Comment: maXp difference is that its printed rounded with a single decimal: `%.1f`, which in my opinion is more human readable and useful if you use that output in other scripts.

Comment: thanks, this helped me. how to put this behind `watch` to be able to get overall cpu usage updated every couple seconds?

Comment: @NaveenReddyMarthala : If you can create a script, its easier. I was unable to make it work with `watch`, but I guess its possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-n2`. This will output two lines. The 1st time `top` prints the line does not qualify for the state at that point in time. Then adjust your script to ignore the first line.

Answer (score 0):

I needed CPU usage per core and used mpstat from the sysstat package.

```
sudo apt install sysstat
```

CPU0 Utilization in %:

```
echo 100 - $(mpstat -P 0 | tail -1 | awk '{print $13}') | bc
```

CPU1 Utilization in %:

```
echo 100 - $(mpstat -P 1 | tail -1 | awk '{print $13}') | bc
```

Change the -P X if you have more than 2 cores.

Comment: This reports average CPU utilization since boot, which is not what has been asked for.

Answer (score 0):

With a very small delay (500 ms approx), the current CPU usage in % can be found out using the following command

```
awk '{u=$2+$4; t=$2+$4+$5; if (NR==1){u1=u; t1=t;} else print ($2+$4-u1) * 100 / (t-t1) "%"; }' <(grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat) <(sleep 0.5;grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat)
```