# Minecraft Framerate Drop after 5 minutes

Tags: 13.10, java, games, minecraft

I installed 13.10 last night on a Dell Precision M6500 and I was amazed that I could get ~50 FPS, but then after about 5 minutes, it took a sudden drop to about 2 FPS. This happens every time and framerate will not go back up unless I kill all java processes and restart Minecraft. How can I prevent this frame drop?

Comment: Have you tried to [monitor](http://askubuntu.com/questions/293426/system-monitoring-tools-for-ubuntu) your system while Minecraft is running? I imagine Minecraft is very memory intensive.

Comment: Yeah, I ran htop while I was playing, and it just showed basically all resources full, even if it was running fine 5 minutes ago