# Can't isntall PySensors. "sudo pip install PySensors" generates "ValueError: /usr/bin/python: undefined symbol: libsensors_version"

Tags: python, pip

I'm just trying to get "Glances" working as per the accepted post in this question:
[System Monitoring Tools For Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293426/system-monitoring-tools-for-ubuntu)

But I can't install PySensors. The command `sudo pip install PySensors` throws an error

```
ValueError: /usr/bin/python: undefined symbol: libsensors_version
```

I have also tried downloading the source and building it from there, but I get (almost) the same error message:

```
ValueError: python: undefined symbol: libsensors_version
```

*Note: glances seems to still work, but I'm assuming it's missing some info due to PySensors not being installed.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my case LMSensor was missing. Running `sudo apt-get install lm-sensors`then`sudo pip install pysensors` worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

the latest Glances version do not use the PySensors lib but py3sensors.

To install a fresh Glances stack:

```
pip install psutil
pip install zeroconf
pip install netifaces
pip install bottle
pip install batinfo
pip install https://bitbucket.org/gleb_zhulik/py3sensors/get/tip.tar.gz
pip install matplotlib
```

Note 1: psutil need Python dev (apt-get install python-dev)

Note 2: matplotlib needs another deps (apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib)

Note 3: py3sensors needs LMsensor (apt-get install lm-sensors)

Then:

```
pip install --upgrade glances
```

or

```
pip install glances
```

Enjoy.