# Ubuntu Samba Server is Taking a Long Time to Load Directories

Tags: networking, server, samba

I have Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS running a Samba File server. One issue I seem to be having is whenever the server is running and I got to a PC to look at the server, it will show the first layer but when I open that layer up it won't show the layer below that unless I go back to the previous layer and let it sit there. This happens for every level down to the file level. Once it loads up, everything runs fine its just the first time that doesn't load in any semblance of speed.

I am new to Ubuntu Server and Samba so it could be something simple I am missing, I'm just not sure.

I am running Samba Version 4.1.6-Ubuntu

Years later I tried again and no problems, incorrect conf file I suspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have the definitive answer to this problem, but i experienced a similar problem with the follow system links enabled in the smb.conf file.

What are the specs of the machine you are using? ( I doubt this has a major effect)

Have you tried using a system monitoring tool like [Glances](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Glances) to watch the performance of your server as you access these folders, a good guide to installation can be found on [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293426/system-monitoring-tools-for-ubuntu).

If you add your smb.conf file into your original question it may provide more insight (Please strip all the default comments if you are going to do so)