# What kernel options should I use to enable 4 cores in my intel processor?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, xubuntu

On my ASUS GL552VW laptop (with 4 cores intel i5-6300HQ processor) with Xubuntu 16.10 32bit and kernel 4.8.0, I was having video playing in chromium and I launch `npm install` in ansi term in emacs 25 and there was a lag when I move my mouse and CPU indicator show 100%.

Is it because 4 cores wasn't working? If so then what kernel options should I use to enable 4 cores in my processor? Or maybe it's because nvidia drivers?

I have this in my `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="
```

the output of `sudo lshw -class cpu` show one core enabled, different then the other question so it's not duplicate:

```
  *-cpu                     
       description: CPU
       product: AMD Sempron(tm) M120
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
       physical id: 4
       bus info: cpu@0
       version: 15.6.2
       serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       slot: CPU 1
       size: 2100MHz
       capacity: 2100MHz
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 200MHz
       capabilities: x86-64 boot fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp 3dnowext 3dnow constant_tsc rep_good nonstop_tsc extd_apicid eagerfpu pni monitor cx16 popcnt lahf_lm svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt hw_pstate vmmcall npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save cpufreq
       configuration: cores=1 enabledcores=1 threads=1
```

out of `LC_ALL=C lscpu`

```
Architecture:          i686
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                1
On-line CPU(s) list:   0
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             1
Vendor ID:             AuthenticAMD
CPU family:            16
Model:                 6
Model name:            AMD Sempron(tm) M120
Stepping:              2
CPU MHz:               800.000
CPU max MHz:           2100.0000
CPU min MHz:           800.0000
BogoMIPS:              4200.05
Virtualization:        AMD-V
L1d cache:             64K
L1i cache:             64K
L2 cache:              512K
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm 3dnowext 3dnow constant_tsc rep_good nonstop_tsc extd_apicid eagerfpu pni monitor cx16 popcnt lahf_lm svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt hw_pstate vmmcall npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save
```

Comment: @George if `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -E "(core|model\ name)"` return 4 cores does it mean that all cores are enabled?

Comment: If you have `htop` run that and you should see the cores in use...

Comment: Yes it does.. sorry use `system monitor`

Comment: @George where can I find system monitor?  I've search but can't find it, also this question doesn't help [System Monitoring Tools For Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/293426/system-monitoring-tools-for-ubuntu)

Comment: It's installed by default, so click you `windows command button` `Dash` will show then type `system monitor` and select it. Look under processes. Better still type `top` in terminal and `press 1` to see the cores running

Comment: @George I've run `sudo lshw -class cpu` and it show one core different then other question so it's not duplicate.

Comment: Are you sure it's on Xubuntu because it seems that I don't have it. I only have  xfce4-taskmanager.

Comment: ok sorry thought you were using Ubuntu unity

Comment: Can you add the output of `lscpu`?

Comment: @ByteCommander add output of lscpu. I'm using 32bit system don't know if that change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've removed `acpi_osi=` from boot options and now I have intel CPU with 4 cores. I thought that's needed for keyboard back lighting and fn keys, but it work without it.