# How to uninstall glances

Tags: command-line, uninstall

I have used only this command to install glances:

```
curl -L bit.ly/glances | sudo /bin/bash
```

Now I need to remove all the stuff that this command installed including glances. How can I do that?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like the script uses `pip` to install `glances`. Do you see `glances` if you run `pip list`?

Comment: @edwinksl sorry But I am really noob in Linux how  can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

[Glances](https://github.com/nicolargo/glances/) author (Nicolas Hennion) just answered me that exact question.

> The script is based on Pipy. So you can uninstall Glances with a simple:
>
> ```
> sudo pip uninstall glances
> ```

[`pip` doesn't uninstall the dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10284948/4970442). It only removes the specified package. As long as [this issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5823) isn't soved we can use [`pip-autoremove`](https://pypi.org/project/pip-autoremove/).

Comment: This will not remove dependencies installed by Glances. The OP should look at the content of the file in `bit.ly/glances` to see what need to be removed.

Comment: I edited my answer taking account of this issue. Shouldn't be necessary to read the installer script.

Answer (score 2):

You ran a script which have installed some packages on your system, what you have to do is to remove all of them.

Here is a list of packages:

```
git python-pip python-dev gcc lm-sensors wireless-tools
```

see which one of them you don't want anymore then remove them.

it also installs some requirements using `pip`, I guess you can remove them using:

```
sudo pip uninstall -r glances/requirements.txt 
sudo pip uninstall -r glances/optional-requirements.txt
```

it also creates a directory named `glances` where you ran the installation script, remove it simple as `rm -r glances`.

Comment: This should be accepted as answer. I'd like to add that you also need to remove a binary file in `/usr/local/bin/glances` or `/usr/bin/glances` and run `pip uninstall glances` to remove Glances itself.