# How do I find what is using all my RAM?

Tags: 20.04, ram-usage

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04. I just switched from Windows a few weeks ago. I have 32GB RAM, which should be plenty even for what I'm doing, but I've had games crashing and after investigation I seem to constantly be at 95-99% memory usage. Looking at the system monitor "Processes" page, I should only be using around 10GB or so, but on the "Resources" page it is showing 30+. Even after a complete reboot, getting all my normal programs up brought it straight to 22GB or so on the "Resources" page (still just 10 according to "Processes"), then over several hours it climbed back to max out without opening any new programs. I can't track down the offending program efficiently if it isn't showing in the processes, so what can I do?

I checked buffer/cache mentioned in previous questions/answers and that accounts for only a small amount of the discrepancy. I also read there was a memory leak in GNOME a while back, but restarting it didn't change the used memory at all.

Processes:

[image: Processes]
<sup>(Click images to enlarge)</sup>

Resources:

[image: Resources]

Console buffer check

[image: Console Buffer Check]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What system monitoring tools are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293426/what-system-monitoring-tools-are-available)