# zoom usage and what is happening?

Tags: system, zooming, zoom-meeting

I normally use zoom for teleworking on my windows machine.
Today I tried to use zoom (from the browser only since I don't have it installed) from my linux machine

There appear the homepage where it said

```
Click Open Zoom Meetings on the dialog shown by your browser
If you don’t see a dialog, click Launch Meeting below
```

Since there was no dialog I just pressed "Launch Meeting"

Nothing happened.... except that now my linux machine seems to be using a lot of resources , and the fan is making a sound like when I do ML training in it.

So, what happened when I press that button and how can I check that whatever happened is not using my resources?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What system monitoring tools are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293426/what-system-monitoring-tools-are-available)