# Any way to monitor the resources of my system over time?

Tags: 20.04, docker, monitoring

Let's say I want to know how much RAM and how much CPU I consumed after an hour of having the system started, but I don't want to have `top` opened and be looking at it all the time.

I want a program that can write the resource usage to some kind of graph so I can look at it and see which resources I have been using at what time. I don't need it to be CLI, maybe a web app or a docker...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably you are looking for something like `conky`: https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky Check this link (and links that you can find on your favourite search engine) to discover the potentialities of conky (and if it fits your needs).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What system monitoring tools are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293426/what-system-monitoring-tools-are-available)

Comment: Do you need something that works in the background, but you can check anytime soon to see the resources used?

Comment: exactly @Tyþë-Ø

Comment: I think it's possible to create a script for that. Like you open the script then it shows "the last most used resources"

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is system monitoring. I use [monitorix](https://www.monitorix.org/)
It's open source system monitoring tool and exist in Ubuntu repository.
You can install it via:

```
sudo apt install monitorix
sudo systemctl start monitorix
```

Then open the link in your browser :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/monitorix
```

More info:
https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-use-monitorix-for-system-monitoring/
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/monitorix