# Show CPU usage using a command

Tags: command-line, server, cpu

I want to see CPU usage.
I used this command :

```
top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | 
           sed "s/.*, *\([0-9.]*\)%* id.*/\1/" | 
           awk '{print 100 - $1}'
```

But it returns 100%.
What's the correct way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To get cpu usage, best way is to read /proc/stat file. See `man 5 proc` for more help.

There is a useful script written by Paul Colby i found [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/linuxkernelnewbies@googlegroups.com/msg01690.html)

```
#!/bin/bash
# by Paul Colby (http://colby.id.au), no rights reserved ;)

PREV_TOTAL=0
PREV_IDLE=0

while true; do

  CPU=(`cat /proc/stat | grep '^cpu '`) # Get the total CPU statistics.
  unset CPU[0]                          # Discard the "cpu" prefix.
  IDLE=${CPU[4]}                        # Get the idle CPU time.

  # Calculate the total CPU time.
  TOTAL=0

  for VALUE in "${CPU[@]:0:4}"; do
    let "TOTAL=$TOTAL+$VALUE"
  done

  # Calculate the CPU usage since we last checked.
  let "DIFF_IDLE=$IDLE-$PREV_IDLE"
  let "DIFF_TOTAL=$TOTAL-$PREV_TOTAL"
  let "DIFF_USAGE=(1000*($DIFF_TOTAL-$DIFF_IDLE)/$DIFF_TOTAL+5)/10"
  echo -en "\rCPU: $DIFF_USAGE%  \b\b"

  # Remember the total and idle CPU times for the next check.
  PREV_TOTAL="$TOTAL"
  PREV_IDLE="$IDLE"

  # Wait before checking again.
  sleep 1
done
```

save it to `cpu_usage`, add execute permission `chmod +x cpu_usage` and run:

```
./cpu_usage
```

to stop the script, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>

Comment: its always showing 0% on tx.2large EC2 instance. What's the issue? while the cloudwatch showing 23%

Answer (score 41):

Why not use `htop` [interactive process viewer]? In order to install it, open a terminal window and type:

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```

Also see `man htop` for more information and how to set it up.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution which works nicely, here it is:

```
top -bn2 | grep '%Cpu' | tail -1 | grep -P  '(....|...) id,'
```

I am not sure but it looks to me that the first iteration of `top` with the `-n` parameter returns some dummy data, always the same in all my tests.

If I use `-n2` then the second frame is always dynamic. So the sequence is:

1. Get the 2 first frames of top: `top -bn2`
2. Then from those frames take only the lines that contain '%Cpu': `grep '%Cpu'`
3. Then only take the last occurrence/line: `tail -1``
4. Then get the idle value ( has 4 or 5 chars, a space, "id,"): `grep -P  '(....|...) id,'`

Hope it helps,
Paul

[image]

Comment: Not really "dummy data", but yes, the first iteration of `top` has no previous sample to compare its data to, hence the apparent *nonsense*. See [this comment](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=174619#c3).