# CPU usage command line

Tags: command-line, cpu

I want to get the cpu usage. I tried this command

```
top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | sed "s/.*, *\([0-9.]*\)%* id.*/\1/" | awk '{print 100 - $1}'
```

Could you confirm if this command is correct?

Comment: Which version of `top`?

Comment: This question have been asked before. [Link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/274349/getting-cpu-usage-realtime)